# It's a small world and no error! (an exclamation of surprise) - what does "no error" mean?

Tags: idioms

In the movie "[In Which We Serve](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034891/)", a sailor strucks an acquaintance with a girl on a train and a short while after asks his father how did he get to know his future wife. The father replies that he met her on a train. The sailor says:

> Well, it's a small world, *and no error!*

That seemed like a set expression of surprise, but I found only one other instance **[here](http://books.google.ru/books?id=ePqnRu50dWIC&lpg=PA370&ots=mlwUt8lx5m&dq=%22small%20world%20and%20no%20error%22&hl=ru&pg=PA370#v=onepage&q=%22small%20world%20and%20no%20error%22&f=false)**.

I wonder what the words "no error" could mean. Do they mean "indeed", "no doubt about it", that is, about the fact that *it's a small world*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't heard 'and no error', but it is very probably the same as ['and no mistake'](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/and-no-mistake), which is is used to emphasize the statement before it. You're correct that 'indeed' and 'no doubt about it' convey the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks! It's used later in the movie: "If I wasn't so tired I'd give them a cheer, *and that's no error*". Seems to be a variation on "and no mistake".

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily trust the dialogue in that movie (where *and no error* occurs no less than ***three*** times) to be representative of *actual* speech at the time. I seriously doubt Noel Coward had much experience of how "commoners" spoke, and he accounts for both different instances of *"small world and no error"* in Google Books. FWIW, there are ***nine*** instances of *"small world and no **mistake**"*, and one of those is also from Noel Coward (in *Blithe Spirit*, which I think is *much* better as a movie).